# Pandas group by row based values based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I need to find event names, date and value (of the column) which meet a condition from the below data using Pandas. I want to find the if any events processed value is less than it's own average value for that particular event.

[image: Original Data]

The condition is for any event_name,

```py
number_of_items_processed < avg(number_of_items_processed)
```

The output I am looking for is,

[image: Output for each event]

Comment: I think it is better you use from table format for display your data. Also you can place a simple code for dataframe creation. These can improve your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use from this code:

```py
df['m']=df.groupby(by=['event'])['number_of_processed'].transform('mean')

df=df[df.number_of_processed<df.m]
```